# React Router matching issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following routes in my Routes.js:

```
const init = () => {
        return JSON.parse("{}");
    }

const initDraft = () => {
    return {
        "open": true,
        "questions": [],
        "author": 'Author',
        "category": '1',
        "level": ''
    };
}

const [sessionTest, dispatchTest] = useReducer(testReducer, {}, init);
const [draftTest, dispatchDraft] = useReducer(createTestReducer, {}, initDraft);

<Route exact path="/tests" component={SelectTest} />

<CreateTestContext.Provider value={{ draftTest, dispatchDraft }}>
        <Route exact path="/draft" component={CreateTest} />
</CreateTestContext.Provider>

<TestContext.Provider value={{ sessionTest, dispatchTest }}>
        <Route exact path="/tests/:testId" render={(props) => <CompleteTest props={{ ...props }} />} />
</TestContext.Provider>
```

The problem is, when I try to access `/test/d567c9ce5a09a05de6cceaea7cac34d8` I am not being redirected to the `CompleteTest` component, but to the second, `CreateTest`.
If I reorder the routes and place the third one as the second and viceversa, I am able to access to `/test/d567c9ce5a09a05de6cceaea7cac34d8` and `CompleteTest` is being loaded but if I try to go to `/draft` then React won't load `CreateTest`, it is loading `CompleteTest` again.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please try without exact match?

Comment: @rnr I've tried several combinations with and without exact and it's not working

Comment: Can you try with , 1st exact path for /tests, 2nd not exact /tests/:testId, 3rd exact /draft

Comment: @rnr It didn't work. Maybe there's something with having two contexts in the same js file? I am a beginner to React

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work with this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const PrivateRoute = ({
    isAuthenticated,
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest}
            component={(props) => (
                (isAuthenticated) ?
                    (<Component {...props} />)
                    : <Redirect to="/login" />
            )}
        />
    )
}

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    component: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

And now in my routes file:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/draft" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated()} component={CreatorRoutes}></PrivateRoute>
<PrivateRoute path="/tests" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated()} component={TestRoutes}></PrivateRoute>
```

CreatorRoutes:

```
return (
        <>

            <CreateTemplateContext.Provider value={{ draftTest, dispatchDraft }}>
                <Route exact path="/draft/test" component={CreateTest} />
                <Route exact path="/draft/question" component={AskQuestion} />
            </CreateTemplateContext.Provider>

        </>
    )
```

TestRoutes:

```
return (
        <>
            <TestContext.Provider value={{ sessionTest, dispatchTest }}>
                <Route exact path="/tests" component={SelectTest} />
                <Route exact path="/tests/:testId" render={(props) => <CompleteTest props={{ ...props }} />} />
            </TestContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
```

I don't know what was the problem with the previous approach... but this is doing the trick.